# Is the .NET framework required for even a single line of VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I wrote very simple code to send emails. I wish that end users who do not have [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) Framework installed, could also install this application without installing .NET Framework.
Is it possible?

Comment: What operating system do you expect your clients to be using? The .Net Framework has been a part of the base OS install since Vista (After all, XP is no longer part of mainstream support by Microsoft)

Comment: @Rowland Windows [isn't guaranteed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/04/10149346.aspx) to have .Net. It can be removed in the control panel in Vista and 7. (Not sure about 8)

Comment: @MarkJ it isn't guaranteed, but it is part of the base install, which is what I'd said. For Windows 8 you should declare code as forward compatible (if it is) or target a later version of the framework, as v3.5 of the Framework is not installed by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are developing a web application then [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) Framework required only on the server where you host the application, not for client machines.

But for a desktop application .NET Framework is an essential requirement for every machine where you use your application even if it has only a single line of code.

Answer (score 10):

The [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) Framework is required on your client machines, even for a single line of .NET code.

This applies only to client code; [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET), which runs on a separate machine and serves up HTML, does not require the .NET Framework on the consuming PC.

You might be interested in the [.NET client profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx). Applications written against this .NET framework subset require a much smaller install (approximately 28 MB) than that required by standard .NET applications.