# Do VB .net Apps absolutely require .net framework to run?

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the .Net framework required for even a single line of VB.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767309/is-the-net-framework-required-for-even-a-single-line-of-vb-net)

I'm getting my programming feet wet by designing a simple vb .net program to run utilities and installations from a flash drive.  I'm making good progress with the coding and design but I was surprised when I went to show off my work on a system with a fresh XP installation and got a "Not valid win32 application" error when I started the exe.  Pretty embarrassing actually.

Is having the .net framework installed essential to loading a .exe coded in vb .net?    If this is the case, is the only alternative to try and adapt the code to vbs script or something similar?  Are there any other reasonable workarounds short of installing .net on the target system?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

It's named VB`.Net` for just that reason. :)

Adapting the code to VB6 (which needs a different series of DLLs installed on the target machine) or to VBScript will likely be quickest.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if it would be possible to make a vbscript that does a check for .net installation, and if one isn't found, does a quick silent install of .net then launches the vb .net application?

Comment: I would advise against VbScript. Best Approach would be to ship your program with an installer wo checks for your net version.
This is possible with WiX for Vb.NET. If you feal really adventorous, you could try to build an bootstrapper installer with burn (component of WiX), top. But this is complicated - but using an WiX installer who Checks for net and aborts if nothing found is fairly simple.

Comment: or just use CLickOnce Deployment or an install project to create a basic installer that will check for the .net framework

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VB.Net does require the .Net Framework. However, Windows XP is getting pretty old now, and recently dropped below a 25% installed base on some indexes. Windows 7 ships with .Net 2.0 out of the box, and Windows 7 sp1 also has .Net 3.5 at least available on the machine.

Comment: Even Windows 7 [isn't guaranteed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/04/10149346.aspx) to have .Net. It can be removed in the control panel.